# by clicking on TextView i want to see the list of items

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my android application, i want to display a list of items when i click on a Textview, it display a list of items and i can add and delete items from that list. how can i do it through java code
Kindly guide. i will be very thankful to you

my code is:

```
 <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cus_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cus_name_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/contact_no"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contact_no_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/ticket_no"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ticket_no_txta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <requestFocus />

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/task_detail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/task_detail_txt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what problem you are getting to populate list of items on textView Click?

Comment: This question is a bit broad.  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: i jst dont know ho to use listview with textViews. as i want to click on cus_name it gives the list of customer name?? kindly guide?

Comment: imran where is your helpful code???

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right I would suggest extending a `Dialog` to make custom dialog that pops out whenever user clicks on `TextView` (as included in Imran Khan's answer). This dialog would contain `ListView` and whatever else you need for handling the list. Example of such approach as I used it some time ago:

```
public class LogOverlay extends Dialog{
private Server mItem;
private boolean end=false;  
private int mLimitHigh = 15;
private int mLimitLow = 0;
private ListView mListView;
private LogListAdapter mAdapter;        
private ArrayList<LogUnit> mLog = new ArrayList<LogUnit>();
private boolean mScroll;    
private Context context;
ProgressDialog pd;


public LogOverlay(Context context,Session session,Server server) {
    super(context);     
    this.setContentView(R.layout.overlay_logs);


    mListView=(ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.log_list);
    mAdapter = new LogListAdapter(context, new ArrayList<LogUnit>(), new String[] {});

    mListView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
    mListView.setDividerHeight(1);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        ....


                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```